# How to optimise something when multiple parameters change the output

Tags: simulation, optimization

This dilemma seems to occurs all the time in so many different engineering problems. It seems impossible to optimise something with multiple parameters, for three reasons:

- There are too many possible combinations of these parameters to be able to simulate them all
- You optimise one parameter at a time, but then you don't know if your final result is the best possible result. E.g: You start with a neural network with 5 layers, and 4 neurons in each layer. You perform a sweep on the number of layers in the neural network, plotting the accuracy of the network vs number of layers. You find that the optimum number is 3 Layers. You then optimise the number of neurons in the first layer, and find that the optimum is 10 neurons, then you optimise the number in the second layer and find 7 is the best, and then the number in the third and find that 6 is the best. **However**, this might not be the best overall solution: For example the accuracy of the network might be better if you start by using 3 neurons in the first layer, which is not the optimum, and then optimise the number in the second and third layer, finding that you get a different number of neurons but a much better accuracy compared to the first method.
- You optimise parameter 1 that governs property **X**, and then you optimise parameter 2 that governs property **Y**, but then this has changed property **X**, so you go back and optimise the parameter 1, but then this changes property **Y**.

This seems like a very fundamental problem when designing any system in any area of engineering, and I thought that there may be a standard method of approaching this problem, or at least a few known methods that do a pretty good job. If there is a solution to this dilemma, can somebody please tell me?

---

*Additional Details*

The neural network example is the problem I am currently having, but I'll give another example of this problem I have had in the past. I was trying to design a patch antenna that will have a resonant frequency of 2GHz. The resonant frequency is mainly dependant on the width of the patch, and the gain of the antenna was mainly dependant on the insertion depth. In CST, I performed a sweep on the width and picked the value that gave the lowest s parameter at 2GHz, I then performed a sweep on the insertion depth and picked the value that reduces the S parameter to the lowest value (I decided that -40dB was acceptable). But this then changed the frequency at which this gain happens, so I did a sweep on the width again, and I picked the value that gave the lowest s parameter, but now the s parameter is too high again, so I optimise the insertion depth... and so on.

Comment: If you feel that this question is on the wrong stack exchange site please tell me. There is no site for general engineering questions so i thought I would post here.

Comment: So, did you eventually converge on an optimal solution, or did it just keep cycling around?

Comment: It just kept cycling around. I tried reducing the step interval size of the sweep and the mesh size of the simulation to see if this would solve the problem, but an optimal solution was never found. But out of curiosity, is this iterative process of optimising one thing and then another, hoping it converges, an accepted method? Or are there better ways?

Comment: Also, even if it did converge on a solution, how can I guarantee that this is the optimal one? _Refer to point bullet point 2 in my question_

Comment: You can't. In the most general case, you can't make that guarantee without an exhaustive search of the solution space. Also, when you have more than one performance metric, it isn't generally possible to optimize them all at once, and you have to be prepared to compromise.

Comment: So happy I found this thread! Having the exact same problem at the moment

Comment: @LukeTaylor I found it helpful to think about the problem as a 3d graph. Two of the axis are variables you would like to optimise, and the third axis is a measure of how good the design is.
This can be extended into higher dimensions with more than two variables (it becomes difficult to visualise this if you think about it too hard!).
Look into local and global optimisation methods, and these will teach you how to search this variable space for an optimum (or near optimum) design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, those problems are often solved with [metaheuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic), like [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithms): they have been [successfully applied in solving engineering problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genetic_algorithm_applications).

I don't know how well it would apply to your case, but antenna design [has been](http://alglobus.net/NASAwork/papers/Space2006Antenna.pdf) [done](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~wbl/biblio/gecco2002/RWA167.pdf) using genetic algorithms.

Comment: I don't know enough about genetic algorithms to know when they are the best solution, but they definitely produce the kind of far-out designs that I just love to see.

Comment: You just gave me a Eureka moment. At the start of this project my supervisor mentioned Genetic Algorithms. I assumed that this was an alternative learning algorithm to back propagation (which it can be, and I have implemented). It didn't occur to me that he meant use the the GA to optimise the network architecture. Although it seems weird using a GA to optimise something that will be using a GA to optimise something else...

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive control, a la Astrom and Wittenmark, seems like a valid approach.  Model a complicated system as a simple system, and allow the model parameters to drift by a recursive least squares algorithm and a forgetting factor.  This is a specific form of Kalman filtering, if I recall correctly, and many have argued that neural net algorithms are very similar to the RLS algorithm, converging by the same rules (though I don't know where that argument lies today -- it's been a while for me)

Comment: Is this another Heuristic algorithm as mentioned by @Renan ? The method you describe sound to me similar to particle swarm optimisation. Is this correct?

Comment: Nope...it's model based

Answer (score 0):

An iterative computation should include the calculation of sensitivity (Derivative), the error (Proporotional) and the accumulated error (Integral) just as a PID compensation controls in the fastest time with minimal overshoot.

NN uses Jacobian Matrix and Determinant and may require some fine tuning for sensitivity.

Process Controls with many variables use the Design of Experiment (DOE) approach (aka Taguchi method) where tolerances 0, +x%,-x% are simultaneously changed to determine the sensitivity of each variable for optimizing a process with very few iterations. ( e.g. 10 vs 1000 ) ( depending on permutations or combinations)

This is a just  brief summary but it is also critical to determine the sensitivity so that a tolerance analysis can be done. Another variable is dielectric constant with resonant frequency, which reduces as frequency increases in your range.